Applying Wronskian Method to Differential Equations
Let $y^{"}+p(x)y=0,$ where $p(x)$ is a continuous function. let $y_{1}(0)=0, y_{1}^{'}(0)=1, y_{2}(0)=-1, y_{2}^{'}(0)=1, W(y_{1},y_{2})$ is a Wronskian of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$
$(A).$ $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ are L.I.
$(B).$ if $p(x)=sinx$ then $y_{1}(\pi) + y_{2}^{'}(\pi)=2$.
$(C).$ If $p(x) = cosx$ differential equation has non trivial periodic solution with period \pi if $y_{1}(\pi) + y_{2}^{'}(\pi)=2$.
$(D).$ If $p(x) = sin(2x)$ differential equation has periodic non trivial solution with period $\Rightarrow$ $y_{1}(\pi) + y_{2}^{'}(\pi)=2$.
For $(A)$: $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ are linearly independent. So,  Wronskian formula says, $W(y_{1},y_{2})$ =
\begin{vmatrix} 
 y_{1}(x) & y_{2}(x) \\ y_{2}^{'}(x) & y_{2}^{'}(x)
\end{vmatrix}
At $x=0,$
$W(y_{1},y_{2})$ =
\begin{vmatrix} 
 y_{1}(0) & y_{2}(0) \\ y_{2}^{'}(0) & y_{2}^{'}(0)
\end{vmatrix}
$W(y_{1},y_{2})$ =
\begin{vmatrix} 
 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$W(y_{1},y_{2}) = 0-0 = 0$
Clearly $y_{1}(0)$ & $y_{2}(0)$ are linearly dependent. Hence option $(A)$ is discarded.
How to solve other options ? please help thank in advance

Better write y' for the first and y'' for the second derivative. And \sin, \cos .

@Martin R.  You mean $\sin(x)$ & $\cos(x)$ right?

You transferred $y_2(0)=1$ with a wrong value into the matrix. Please check your initial conditions, is there really a $-1$ as value?

Similar questions that might give some insight into the solution of this one are https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266352/yaxyx-0-quad-ax-is-continuous-function-with-period-t, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828864/differential-equations-wronskian-periodic-solutions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143428/proving-ode-does-not-have-bounded-solutions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407686/deducing-the-periodicity-of-basis-functions-from-the-periodicity-of-a-particular.

@Lutz Lehmann "Thanks a ton! I really need this."

You could take a numerical solver to test if the claims are even close. By the linked topics, only (D) has to be true, for the others I'm not sure if there would be a reason for the values at the half-periods to satisfy this identity, even with an existing periodic solution.
